# Woocommerce: How to Add extra fee for First Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add Extra Fee in the total of cart/order amount only if this is first order of Customer.

I searched a lot online but I still did not find any specific solution yet.

Please someone suggest/guide the best solution to perferm this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the cart class' `add_fee()` method to add a fee. There's no built-in way to know how many orders a customer has made, so we can try to track that via a user meta field called `_number_order`.

```
function so_27969258_add_cart_fee() {
    $orders = intval( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_number_orders', true ) );
    if( $orders < 1 ){
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __( 'First time fee', 'your-plugin'), 100 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'so_27969258_add_cart_fee' );
```

If we don't actually update the `_number_orders` key, then it will always be null/empty/zero and the user will always be charged the first time fee. So we can try to update that key when the user completes payment.

```
function so_27969258_track_orders_per_customer(){
    $orders = intval( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_number_orders', true ) );
    $orders = $orders + 1;
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_number_orders', $orders );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_27969258_track_orders_per_customer' );
```

This is totally untested, so use at your own risk. Also, you might want to look into changing the number of orders total in case of refunds/cancellations, etc, but this seems like the general gist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solved my serious Issue. 
I made some minor changes in first function:

      `add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','so_27969258_add_cart_fee' );

function so_27969258_add_cart_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $orders = intval( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_number_orders', false ) );
   
    if( $orders < 1 ){
        
       $fee=1;
         $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'First Time Fee', $fee, true, 'standard' );
    }
}
`
Everything is working like charm. 
Thanks again :)

Comment: The global `$woocommerce` is deprecated and `WC()` should be used instead for retrieving the instance of the WooCommerce class.

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks for useful information. Now I will use WC(). Thanks again for everything thing. I really appreciate it.

Comment: To add, in your second function you don't use `$orders` once you've incremented it... I know it's untested but it's crucial to increment the value if the function is to work...

Comment: Good catch, @BigChris. I've updated the `update_user_meta()` to have a value.